# Create XML from gridview

Tags: jquery, xml, gridview

I wanted to ask if there is a way to create an XML type structure by looping through a gridview using jQuery.

I have the following gridview:

```
Year   Price   Model User
2013   1000    Car   Joe
2013   2000    Car   Josh
2014   1000    Car   Chris
2014   2000    Car   Tresa
```

I want the "XML" type structure to look like the following:

```
 <Car>
 <2013>1000</2013>
 <User>Joe</User>
 <2013>2000</2013>
 <User>Josh</User>
 <2014>1000</2014>
 <User>Chris</User>
 <2014>2000</2014>
 <User>Tresa</User>
 </Car>
```

Comment: Do you want to do this via Javascript only?

Comment: javascript or jquery, if possible. The issue I have is that the grids are dynamically created and so when the users finish editing the rows and click the save button, a postback happens and blows away the grids. I already have a stored procedure that accepts an "xml" like structure to save multiple records at once. My plan was to create an xml-like structure and put it in a hidden field and access that in the code behind after the postback happens.